# Receive audio files from NodeJS Server with React Native App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, file-transfer

I am wondering how one would do something like this. Say I have a React Native app, so I am using my phone. Say I have a million mp3's and I would like to choose one in my app and then download it and play it. How would I send the audio file from my nodejs server to my react native app? I know how to fetch a json or a textfile from my server, but I have no idea how I would do the same thing with larger files, esp. multimedia files.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to download it, surely just play it from an `<audio>` tag, and then you don't need to manage the downloaded files, and it should stream instead of waiting for a download to complete before you can start listening to it

Answer (score 0):

You can host your songs on Cloud Storage ex. Amazon S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/pm/serv-s3) or Google Cloud Storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage). Then,  you can fetch these songs on React Native with the URI pointed to each of the song.